# jQuery load HTML into <div>

Tags: jquery, url, html

Is there a way with jQuery to load Html contents from a url?

For example:

```
<div class="MyContent">

<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World
</body>
</html>

</div>
```

Can I replace all of the HTML above in the div with the content from a URL?

Comment: This is so very ugly. Why not use an iframe?

Comment: Oh, and https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+load - first result. JFGI

Comment: @SomeKittens The same way tables are; only if used improperly.

Comment: ok, but what if some of the pages have lots of content and it needs to scroll? Would not the jquery html content just make the DIV expand, whereas an iFrame would stay the same height? Correct?

Comment: Yes, but why not load only a part of the page. You certainly don't think this is going to work like an iframe...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking for [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Comment: My experience is that people tend not to tell you why they down-vote you. You have to learn to guess your own errors, fix them and get good at it. If I were to guess, it would be that you have no example (especially no jsfiddle or Plunker) and you provided a link and links can eventually get broken (despite it being from a popular site).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, create an HTML page with this code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

Have an iFrame inside a DIV (optional) and change the source of the iFrame to URL using jQuery. The url should point to the page you create above.

```
function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
    var $iframe = $('#' + iframeName);
    if ( $iframe.length ) {
        $iframe.attr('src',url);   
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using `.get()` and `.html()` in jQuery. ex,

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
   $('.MyContent').html(data);
});
```