# How to load remote URL inside sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm using the next code to inject a sidebar. https://github.com/curtislacy/inject-sidebar

```
function handleRequest(
        //The object data with the request params
        request, 
        //These last two ones isn't important for this example, if you want know more about it visit: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html
        sender, sendResponse
        ) {
        if (request.callFunction == "toggleSidebar")
                toggleSidebar();
}
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(handleRequest);

/*Small function wich create a sidebar(just to illustrate my point)*/
var sidebarOpen = false;
function toggleSidebar() {
        if(sidebarOpen) {
                var el = document.getElementById('mySidebar');
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
                sidebarOpen = false;
        }
        else {
                var sidebar = document.createElement('div');
                sidebar.id = "mySidebar";
                sidebar.innerHTML = "\
                        <h1>Hello</h1>\
                        World!\
                ";
                sidebar.style.cssText = "\
                        position:fixed;\
                        top:0px;\
                        left:0px;\
                        width:30%;\
                        height:100%;\
                        background:white;\
                        box-shadow:inset 0 0 1em black;\
                        z-index:999999;\
                ";
                document.body.appendChild(sidebar);
                sidebarOpen = true;
        }
}
```

How can I load a remote URL inside the sidebar instead of using innerHTML?
(Very new to JavaScript)

Comment: The script you copied creates a div and inserts some HTML into it. What you are trying to do is load some external HTML and insert that instead (still through `innerHTML`). Have a look at `jQuery.load` (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130586/jquery-load-html-into-div).

Comment: Mind sharing the code I need to add?

Comment: Couldn't get this to work: `var url = 'http://www.cnn.com';
$("#mySidebar").attr('src', url);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to load a remote URL you have to use an `iframe`. Keep in mind, though, that the remote web-page must allow that (many web-pages don't).

Here is a sample extension, that has a brwoser-action which toggles a sidebar in the active tab.
The sidebar displays `http://www.cnn.com/`.

**In manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts":    ["./bg/background.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
        "js":         ["./fg/content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_idle",
        "all_frames": false
    }],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
        //"default_icon": {
        //    "19": "img/icon19.png",
        //    "38": "img/icon38.png"
        //}
    }
}
```

**In background.js:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "toggleSidebar" });
});
```

**In content.js:**

```
var sidebarURL = "http://www.cnn.com/";

var isSidebarOpen = false;
var sidebar = createSidebar();

/* Create a sidebar */
function createSidebar() {
    var sb = document.createElement("iframe");
    sb.id = "mySidebar";
    sb.src = sidebarURL;
    sb.style.cssText = ""
        + "border:   3px groove;\n"
        + "width:    30%;\n"
        + "height:   100%;\n"
        + "position: fixed;\n"
        + "top:      0px;\n"
        + "left:     0px;\n"
        + "z-index:  9999;\n"
        + "";
    return sb;
}

/* Show/Hide the SideBar */
function toggleSidebar() {
    if (isSidebarOpen) {
        document.body.removeChild(sidebar);
    } else {
        document.body.appendChild(sidebar);
    }
    isSidebarOpen = !isSidebarOpen;
}

/* Listen for message from the background-page and toggle the SideBar */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.action && (msg.action == "toggleSidebar")) {
        toggleSidebar();
    }
});
```

Comment: Great detailed answer. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm trying to run the above on my windows maching and getting `[blocked] The page at https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&espv=210&ie=UTF-8 ran insecure content from http:www.google.com` I'm guessing it's because of the chrome version I'm using. How can I solve it?

Comment: I can't imagine how it could be related to the Chrome version. What exactly are you trying ?

Comment: Took the extension above, changed the url to `http://www.google.com` and run it on my Mac. Works as expected. Took the exact same extension, tried to run it on my windows machine with chrome 30 and got the error above. BTW, if I change the URL to `https://www.google.com` everything works fine. I think that's related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216208/chrome-now-blocking-all-jsonp-requests-from-https-to-http

Comment: The error should show up when a web-page with an `https` tries to fetch data with an `http` scheme. I any way, I could not make it work with google at all on my Windows (because of google's 'SAMEORIGIN' policy), so you should be happy with your situation :D